# File upload using ServerSocket & HTML Client. Stuck at InputStream.read()

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

To understand the concept of socket programming, I created a server and a client. The client will send a file and server should save it some location. (ie. a file upload).

Server:

```
package com.test.socket.server;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ServerSocket serverSocket = new  ServerSocket(8081);

        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Received request");


        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("yoyo.png");

        System.out.println("Reading....");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

        int count = 0;
        while((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0){
        System.out.print(". ");
        out.write(bytes,0,count);
        System.out.println("Some bytes are written");
        }

        System.out.println("written....");

        socket.getOutputStream().write("Written.....".getBytes());

        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
        socket.close();
        serverSocket.close();


    }

}
```

Java client follows:

```
package com.test.socket.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class WebClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket socket = null;
        String host = "127.0.0.1";

        socket = new Socket(host, 8081);

        ///home/renju/Desktop/frame.png

        File file = new File("/home/renju/Desktop/frame.png");

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

        int count = 0;
        while((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0){
            os.write(bytes);
        }

        System.out.println("Sending....");

        os.close();
        inputStream.close();
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

This works fine and writes the uploaded file to my projects root folder.
Now I changed the client to an HTML page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/" method="POST">

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

This is not working in the same fashion as the Java client. For some reason, the execution does not go beyond the `out.write(bytes);` of server code.

Console log..

```
Received request
Reading....
. Some bytes are written
```

What can be the possible reason?

One more question...

Ultimately what I am trying to understand is the purpose of 'multipart/form-data' while uploading a file(once I got the above code working, that is what I am planning to experiment). If someone could give me a hint on that, it will be really helpful.

Comment: To clarify, you can upload an image fine, but when you try to upload the HTML page, this happens?

Comment: Pardon me, I read wrong. Ignore the deleted comment.

Comment: Your Java client isn't speaking HTTP, but your browser client is, so you have to implement HTTP in your server. See RFC 2616 and successors. Too broad.

Comment: Ok. Let me check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine.

No it doesn't. It writes junk at the end of the file, and possibly in other places as well. Your copy loop should be:

```
while((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0){
    System.out.print(". ");
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
```

in both server and client.

> For some reason, the execution does not go beyond the out.write(bytes); of server code.

Actually it is blocking in `read()`, not `write()`. That is because you are now getting an HTTP request, and specifically it is because of HTTP keepalive. See RFC 2616 and successors. The server code you've written will write all the HTTP headers to the target file and then block until the client browser releases the connection, which can take an arbitrary amount of time. You need to *read* and *parse* the headers, specifically the `Content-length` and `Content-encoding` headers, and process the body of the request accordingly, which means only trying to read the number of bytes given in `Content-length`, not read to end of stream, and if the `Content-encoding` is chunked, you need to write some unchunking code.

Comment: No, I verified the file that was uploaded using java client. It is fine. But I am having the issue with HTML client. As you said, it seems to be blocking at read(), but only after the first write in the loop. was I not getting an HTTP request using java client? Sorry for dump questions. I am pretty much novice in Socket, even though I have used the high level libraries.

Comment: No. The copy code is wrong. You may have got incredibly lucky, but don't count on it. It is blocking for the reason I stated. Your Java client isn't speaking HTTP, but the browser is.

Comment: "Your Java client isn't speaking HTTP, but the browser is".... hmm.. i suspect that... i have to think in that way. is that where the mime-type comes into picture?

Answer (score -2):

From oracle docs:

> A socket is one end-point of a two-way communication link between two
>   programs running on the network. Socket classes are used to represent
>   the connection between a client program and a server program. The
>   java.net package provides two classes--Socket and ServerSocket--that
>   implement the client side of the connection and the server side of the
>   connection, respectively.

Simple socket client is :

```
 Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    PrintWriter out =
        new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
```

The `Socket` constructor used here requires the name of the computer and the port number to which you want to connect.

Simple socket server is:

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    PrintWriter out =
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

`ServerSocket` is a java.net class that provides a system-independent implementation of the server side. To accept connection from client `ServerSocket` does:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Comment: hmm.. this is not answering my question.

Comment: You can't transport an image correctly with `Readers` and `Writers`.