# File upload using socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am basically trying to do a file upload(.png files) using Socket in Java.
But at some point execution is infinitely waiting for read() to return results. I do not understand this behavior. can any one help?

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server Code:**

```
private void handlePostFileupload(Socket clientSocket, int contentLength)
        throws IOException {

    InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/renju/opt/WS1/SocketProgrammingTests/upload/file_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));

    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int totalRead = 0;

    while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0){

        totalRead += read;
        System.out.println(totalRead);


        os.write(buffer,0,read);
        os.flush();

        System.out.println("Bytes written...");

        if(totalRead == contentLength){
            System.out.println("Completed uploading....");
            break;
        }
    }

    os.close();


    OutputStream clientOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK ").append("\r\n").append("\r\n")
            .append("<TITLE>").append("SUCCESS").append("</TITLE>");

    String response = sb.toString();

    clientOS.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    clientOS.close();

    clientSocket.close();


}
```

**clinetSocket:**  = serverSocket.accept();
**contentLength** = valueOf("Content-Length");

**HTTP Message:**

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 511715
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: null
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryodqUZ1SAXEBUXSd9
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Console O/P(partial, towards end):**

```
Bytes written...
491520
Bytes written...
492544
Bytes written...
493568
Bytes written...
494592
Bytes written...
495333
Bytes written...
```

Comment: Is this purely a learning exercise? (There's little need to implement HTTP handling yourself when there are plenty of frameworks that will do the heavy lifting for you).

Comment: your data is being sent as multipart form data (not as a regular post where the file is the only data you need to read). So this needs parsing of its own. you need to read until the "boundary" value and take into account a few other values in the stream. i wrote a multi-part parser once and it was annoyingly complicated.

Comment: @Greg, Its purely a learning exercise.@slipperyseal,  I am always ready to push my limits until i get it working. If you have any samples, please post it. Or a hint will do.

Comment: Are you sure you're stuck in `read()`? Or has the loop ended? That's what I would expect. You don't need to worry about the content-length. The Servlet container does that. Just read to end of stream. Don't flush inside loops.

Comment: @EJP, I was just following your instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024852/file-upload-using-serversocket-html-client-stuck-at-inputstream-read. I read the message structure and started creating servers that can handle HTTP. hope i need to read a lil more to handle multipart. Well I am sure that I am stuck at read().

Comment: @Renju That question is about using TCP sockets to implement HTTP. This question is about a Servlet, whose container already implements HTTP. Most of what I wrote in the question you linked does not apply here.

Comment: @EJP I am still working with the Sockets. I haven't used Servlet here

Comment: In that case scratch everything I said above except the part about not flushing inside loops.

Comment: Can u explain what's wrong with flushing OutputStream inside loop? Is that some kind of standard process?